# lead up to - use

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "The selected pCO2 concentrations represent future ocean acidification scenarios leading up to the year by 2100."

Please explain the expression "leading up to" in this context. Its use is OK here? Thank you,
BD

Answer (score 1):

There is *something* wrong with that sentence, but it's not the use of "leading up to" alone.

Rather, *either* something is "leading up to the year [X]", or it happens "by [the year] X".  "[...] leading up to the year by 2100" is ungrammatical, unless there is an established referent of "the year" *and* 2100 is not a year but some kind of code for a *means* by which the scenarios lead up to the earlier-established year.

"The selected pCO₂ concentrations represent future ocean acidification scenarios leading up to the year 2100" (without "by") would mean that the selected concentrations represent scenarios *covering the time before the year 2100*.  Exactly how long a span that is depends on context.  The period "leading up to" something generally means the time in which the visible precursors to that event occur.

If you dropped "leading up to", and instead wrote "The selected pCO₂  concentrations represent future ocean acidification scenarios by the year 2100" (notice that "by" must come before "the year"), the scenarios would instead be focusing on possible outcomes in 2100, but without explicitly considering the state of the ocean *between* now and then.

Answer (score 0):

You could also strike the word **leading** and the preposition **by**:

> ... up to the year 2100